# What is "-s" option in bash?

Tags: bash

I inherited a bash script from someone. The beginning is adding all files with extension ".bam" to a command list and giving the total count of .bam files.

When I run this, one of my folders returns the wrong number of files... 
I would like to change the script so that all .bam files are recognized, but I'm not sure exactly what it's trying to do.

What is [[ -s $BAM ]]? I looked online but can't seem to find what "-s" bash option is?

```
for BAM in *.bam; do
                if [[ -s $BAM ]]; then
                                INPUT_ARGS="$INPUT_ARGS -I $BAM"
                                let COUNT=$COUNT+1
                fi
done
echo "$COUNT BAM files found."
```

Comment: `help test | grep -- -s` , see just `help test` for more..., try https://shellcheck.net for validating your script.

Comment: Or `man test` or `man [`

Comment: Or `man bash` and look for the `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section.

Comment: Seriously, the `man` pages are the definitive documentation and that should be the first place you look.  Indeed, it is worth reading `man bash` from start to finish to get a good idea of the shell's capabilities.